# How to get laravel storage path using javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel

## ** How to get laravel Storage path in js file**

I want to display dinamic image in laravel from database using jquery ajax, but I can't get Stoage path in js file to put my image name
which is a variable:

```
images.forEach(function (image) {  

        var img = `<img src="http://localhost/storage/${product.image}"`;

});
```

"http://localhost/storage/" works,but I want to replace "http://localhost/storage/" to dinamic url using javascript

Comment: Can you try this http://localhost/{project_name}/public/storage/

Comment: Thanks a lot, and if my project runs on a non-local server, does it work?

Comment: @HaykMargaryan In master blade file of your view you can define a global js variable to use the storage path and then you can use that variable inside this file.

Comment: Are you using the public file system driver? Because the storage path should NEVER be exposed directly.

Comment: No, its working only for local server, if your project url changed links broken at that time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a relative path, which will fix the issue in any server.
As follows

```
images.forEach(function (image) {  
 var img = `<img src="/storage/${product.image}"`;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

To get laravel storage path in js file you can do like:

In your headerfile.blade.php

```
<script>

var storagePath = {!! storage_path() !!}; // old with error

var storagePath = "{!! storage_path() !!}"; // updated and tested
</script>
```

The in js file you can use `storagePath` variable.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: var storagePath = {!! storage_path() !!}
This returned 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Comment: ohh silly syntax mistake  try   var storagePath = "{!! storage_path() !!}";

Answer (score 0):

For that either 1.

> {!! storage_path('app/public') !!}

2.you can pass it with your data of product

or

3.you use model for set the full src of image

```
protected $appends = ['image_url'];
public function getImageUrlAttribute()
    {
        $imageUrl = "";
        if (isset($this->attributes['image']) && $this->attributes['image'] != "") {
            $imageUrl = storage_path('app/public').$this->attributes['image'];
        }
        return $imageUrl;
    }
```

and you can use them in your blade like

```
images.forEach(function (image) {  

        var img = `<img src="${product.image_url}"`;

});
```